# Send request via VPN tunnel inside Network Extension

Tags: ios, macos, vpn, wireguard, networkextension

I'm trying to send a simple request with established VPN connection (`NEPacketTunnelProvider`) and I try to use URLSession.shared which sends traffic outside of the tunnel. But that resource is only available inside the tunnel.

Is there a possible way how to send it via VPN?

P.S. I use WireGuard sdk to establish vpn connection, I as I can see there isn't any api to make such a request.

Here is a request that I sent,instead of `ifconfig.co` I use real domain which is accessible inside the tunnel

```
        let request = URLRequest(url: .init(string: "https://ifconfig.co/json")!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            log("Requestion Status FINISHED")
            if let data = data {
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                log("DataString - \(dataString ?? "NULL")")
            }
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                log("httpResponse status code - \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }
            
            if let error = error {
                log("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        .resume()
```